# matplotlib plot whole data

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-consistency

I've been using matplotlib to plot data in the form of lines.
I want all of the data to be visible at any time, but mpl is giving me strange behaviour while fine zooming:

First image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nccvi.png
Second image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hov79.png

The data is not consistent between different views, and I can't allow that in my application. What can I do to prevent this?

I can't find any method to tell mpl to plot all of the data, it seems that there are only methods for drawing every n'th element or similar (and passing 1 does not help).

NOTE: I am using the Qt backend.

Comment: Please post some sample code and what function calls lead to those plots. Hard to diagnose the problem without knowing what you are using.